# Using section breaks in a for-each loop in a BI Publisher rtf template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I am trying to include a section break in my BI Publisher RTF template so that I can set different print options for different parts of the document.

My template is working fine until I add the section break inside of my for-each loop. I can't figure out exactly what is happening but with the section break, I end up with extra, repeated pages in my output. I cannot find anything online about how to use section breaks in BI or if there are problems with their usage.

I am using the BI Publisher Word Add-on to develop the report.

---

Here are some samples to demonstrate my problem

[Sample RTF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsHpp6UoqyXSnd0TktMWTNtd0F3OU8zMWpXa0EtRTd5Z3VR/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Sample XML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsHpp6UoqyXek1qU0JzSmFBaWJaNWphRUdiWFBzc2NBSDhn/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: What is your desired output? It's not really clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my for loop from for-each-group to for-each@section.

Then I removed the  at the end of the loop. Now the section breaks seem to work as expected, and a section break is automatically added between each loop.